# Repository for SAP SLES

Tags: repo

I'm not familiar with Uyuni.

I installed a Uyuni server to patch SAP systems installed on the SLES 15.

I have created a chanel (in Uyuni) and now I want to insert a repository.
In the Uyuni web interface under Software->Manage->Repositories.

What should I enter there? I need repositories for
-SLES for SAP 15.SP 4,

```
SLES for SAP 15 SP3,
SLES for SAP 15 SP2
```

Where can I find these repositories ? where can I find the links to the SAP SLES 15 SP 4 repository ?
Thanks very much
Best regards

reseached for link
reseached for link